# Quartz with MongoDB - any maintained alternative?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

Do we have support for Quartz with MongoDB officially? I see there is a library https://github.com/michaelklishin/quartz-mongodb . but it was mentioned as it is no longer maintained. at this stage, our application is using MongoDB and just for Quartz, don't want to add another DB (MySQL) to our project. Kindly suggest if it is advisable to use two databases or does Quartz has support for MongoDB.

I understand this is requesting for suggestion / opinion. Any inputs will greatly help us.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Here's the complete [list of forks](https://github.com/michaelklishin/quartz-mongodb/network) to the above repo. Some of them is still active in August.